# Getting XMLHTTP to work with HTTPS

Tags: soap, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to access a soap webservice via classic asp over https, but I get the following error.

> MSXML3.DLL error '800c000e'
>   A security problem occurred.

My code:

```
Function GetASPNetResources()    

Dim returnString 
Dim myXML 
Dim objRequest 
Dim objXMLDoc
Dim strXmlToSend
Dim webserviceurl
Dim webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace

strXmlToSend = "<some valid xml>"
webserviceurl = "https://webserviceurl"
webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace = "appname"

Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
objRequest.open "POST", webserviceurl, False

objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/soap+xml"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "utf-8"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "action", webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace & "GetEstimate"
objRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceSOAPActionNameSpace & "GetEstimate"

Set objXMLDoc = Server.createobject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")

objXMLDoc.loadXml strXmlToSend

objRequest.Send() 

Response.Write  objXMLDoc.load(objRequest.responseXML)

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Did you google for that error ?

```
SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS = 13056
objRequest.setOption 2, SXH_SERVER_CERT_IGNORE_ALL_SERVER_ERRORS
```

Comment: Is ignoring all certificate errors really a good idea?  This means the communications with the server may be insecure

Comment: the common problem is that the vendors certificate does not match their domain name.. this is the only way to bypass it..